# Create a list of int & DateTime in Python

Tags: python, datetime, numpy

How can I create a list (or a numpy array if possible) in python that takes `datetime` objects in the first column and other data types in other columns?

For example, the list would be something like this:

```
list = [[<datetime object>, 0, 0.]
        [<datetime object>, 0, 0.]
        [<datetime object>, 0, 0.]]
```

What is the best way to create and initialize a list like this?

So far, I have tried using `np.empty`, `np.zeros`, and a list comprehension, similar to this:

```
list = [[None for x in xrange(3)] for x in xrange(3)]
```

But if I do this, I would need a `for loop` to populate the first column and there doesn't seem to be a way to assign it in a simpler way like the following:

```
list[0][:] = another_list_same_length
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean something like:

```
In [17]: import numpy as np

In [18]: np.array([[[datetime.now(),np.zeros(2)] for x in range(10)]])
Out[18]: 
array([[[datetime.datetime(2014, 8, 7, 23, 45, 12, 151489),
         array([ 0.,  0.])],
        [datetime.datetime(2014, 8, 7, 23, 45, 12, 151560),
         array([ 0.,  0.])],
        [datetime.datetime(2014, 8, 7, 23, 45, 12, 151595),
         array([ 0.,  0.])],
        [datetime.datetime(2014, 8, 7, 23, 45, 12, 151619),
         array([ 0.,  0.])],
        [datetime.datetime(2014, 8, 7, 23, 45, 12, 151634),
         array([ 0.,  0.])],
        [datetime.datetime(2014, 8, 7, 23, 45, 12, 151648),
         array([ 0.,  0.])],
        [datetime.datetime(2014, 8, 7, 23, 45, 12, 151662),
         array([ 0.,  0.])],
        [datetime.datetime(2014, 8, 7, 23, 45, 12, 151677),
         array([ 0.,  0.])],
        [datetime.datetime(2014, 8, 7, 23, 45, 12, 151691),
         array([ 0.,  0.])],
        [datetime.datetime(2014, 8, 7, 23, 45, 12, 151706),
         array([ 0.,  0.])]]], dtype=object)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! The first one is similar to what I wrote in the question. The use of numpy in the second one might be what I am looking for, but it might have the same issue I pointed out at the end of my question. I have a separate list of timestamps (datetime objects) and I want to populate the first column using that list. Using this method, I will have to use a for loop to achieve that goal. I was curious to know if there is a better way to do it, to avoid a for loop and take advantage of capabilities of lists or arrays in python.

Comment: what is your datetime data in, a list or array?

Comment: It is a list. What I did for now is to use `for loops` and your answer definitely is helpful. But do you think there is a way to assign to the first column of this new array a list of datetime objects without the use of a `for loop`?
something like this: `array[0,:] = list_of_time`

Comment: I just tried doing something like this with the array that you had suggested: `my_array[:,0]=datetime_list` and it worked without the need for a `for` loop. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use `zip`

```
>>> column1 = [1, 1, 1]
>>> column2 = [2, 2, 2]
>>> column3 = [3, 3, 3]
>>> zip(column1, column2, column3)
[(1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 3)]
>>> # Or, if you'd like a list of lists:
... 
>>> [list(tup) for tup in zip(column1, column2, column3)]
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
>>>
```

This would allow you to build-up the columns separately and then combine them.
`column1` could be dates (or anything else.)

Hope this helps.